# cloned drive with 1TB capacity allocated 813GB to WinRE tools, and I can't expand the C drive

Tags: partitioning, clone

I cloned a 120GB SSD to a 1TB ssd using Macrium Reflect. I followed the directions per the following video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7H7D1HcfY9o), but when I booted from the newly-cloned SSD and inspected the new (cloned) drive, it seems to have allocated the same 120GB of the old drive to the new drive as the primary partition, and it allocated the remaining 813GB to WinRE tools. How do I expand the primary partition to have it use the available space that was wrongly allocated to the WinRE partition?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of many reasons why 3rd party cloning tools are not recommended.  Windows natively supports imaging of partitions via **[`DISM`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14)** in Windows >=8, or [**`ImageX`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447(v=ws.10).aspx) in Windows <=7, of which are far superior to 3rd party cloning tools and do not cause configuration issues.

- *It may simply be more efficient to re-image the SSD and re-apply the image via `DISM` or `ImageX`, showing how to do this after the line break below under **Imaging**.*
- If knowing how to re-create the WinRE partition and have not removed its contents from the SSD, simply delete the partition via `DiskPart` or Disk Management (`diskmgmt.msc`), opening either via **<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>**.

  - Once done, you'll be able to expand the system partition and re-create a 512MB WinRE partition 
     *(with its special hex or GUID identifier in `Diskpart`)*

    1. Open Admin terminal via **<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>**

       1. *Open:* `cmd`
       2. While pressing **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** select *OK*, and approve escalation of privileges
       3. Issue: `reagentc /disable`
       4. Issue: `DiskPart`

          1. `sel dis 0`

             - where `0` is the 1TB drive *(list drives via `lis dis`)*
          2. `sel par 3`

             - Where `3` is the WinRE partition *(list partitions via `lis par`)*
          3. `del par`

             - If receiving an error, issue `del par override`
    2. Resize system partition via Disk Management *(don't close `DiskPart`)*

       - Right-click on system partition > *Extend Volume...*
    3. Re-create WinRE partition *(go back to `DiskPart` terminal)*:

       1. MBR: `cre par pri size=512 id=27` 
           GPT: `cre par pri size=512 id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac`

          - Assign correct attributes: `gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001`
       2. Format WinRE partition: `format fs=ntfs quick label=Recovery`
       3. Assign drive letter: `assign letter=z`
       4. Copy files from old drive's WinRE partition to WinRE drive Z:
       5. Re-register WinRE via a *NEW* Admin terminal:

          1. `reagentc /setreimage /path Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE /target C:\Windows`
          2. `reagentc /enable`
       6. Remove WinRE drive letter *(go back to `Diskpart` terminal)*: `remove`

---

### Imaging

When it comes to Windows, 3rd party tools are *not* an efficient way to image a partition.

- Windows has *always* natively supported imaging of partitions or individual directories..

  - *The system partition can only be imaged from WinPE/WinRE, while all other partitions are able to be imaged while booted to Windows.*
  - WIMs *(**W**indows **IM**age)* can be captured of an entire partition or individual folders/files. 
     Create a [**`WimScript.ini`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-configuration-list-and-wimscriptini-files-winnext) config file to specify exclusions or exceptions.
- All WinPE/WinRE  [WIMs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wim-vs-ffu-image-file-formats) have either `ImageX` or `DISM` included within them.

  - **WinPE:** ***Win**dows **P**reinstallation **E**nvironment*

    - *Such as a Windows Setup boot media (**<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>** to access terminal)*
  - **WinRE:** ***Win**dows **R**ecovery **E**nvironment*

    - *WinRE is a WinPE image containing extra [WinPE Optional Components](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference) vital to recovery*

---

#### Commands

*WinPE only has 32MB of scratch [temp] space by default, so `/ScratchDir` is required*

- **Windows >=8: [`DISM`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14)** is utilized

  - Capture an image:

    ```powershell
    DISM /Capture-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2019.09.14 @ 09:25" /Compress:Max /CheckIntegrity /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
    ```
  - Apply an image:

    ```powershell
    DISM /Apply-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.esd" /Index:1 /ApplyDir:"C:" /CheckIntegrity /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
    ```
- **Windows <=7: [`ImageX`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447(v=ws.10).aspx)** is utilized in lieu of `DISM`:

  - Capture an image:

    ```powershell
    ImageX /Capture "C:" "Z:\Base.esd" "Windows Backup" "Base Image 2019.09.14 @ 09:25" /Compress:Recovery /Check /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
    ```
  - Apply an image:

    ```powershell
    ImageX /Apply "Z:\Base.wim" 1 "C:" /Check /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
    ```

---

#### NOTE:

- **It's *impossible* for an ESD/WIM image to become corrupted**

  - Provided imaging commands are *always* issued with:

    - **DISM:** `/CheckIntegrity` & `/Verify`
    - **ImageX:** `/Check` & `/Verify`
- **ESDs can only be taken of a *system* partition**

  - `/Compress:Recovery` is the only compression algorithm available.

    - ESD compression ratio is ~33% more efficient than the WIM compression ratio.
    - *In Windows 10, Microsoft only allows ESDs for Push-Button Reset exported images*
- **ESDs/WIMs are smart compression image formats**

  - Only changed files are added to an image when a new image is appended to it

    - Newly appended images utilize the same copy of unchanged files already contained within the image from the previous image(s).

      - This allows for an image to remain small in relation to the data contained within.

---

#### DISM & ImageX Prerequisites

- **Easy**

  1. Download & create a [bootable USB](https://rufus.ie/):

     - **DISM:** [Windows Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
     - **ImageX:** [Windows 7 Install ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7)
  2. Once booted from it, press: **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>** to open a terminal
  3. [DISM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14) / [ImageX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447(v=ws.10).aspx) commands

     - [Capture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#capture-image) or [Append](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#append-image) an Image
     - [Apply Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#apply-image)

       - Get [Image Info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#get-imageinfo) *(`ImageX /Info`)*, prior to applying, ensuring correct index [image] is being applied.
- **Custom:** *Create a WinPE/RE image*

  1. **Install:**

     - Windows ADK *(8 & 10)* || AIK *(7)* is specific to the version of Windows installed.

       1. **ADK:**

          - For Windows >=10 v1809: [WinPE Addon for ADK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2087112)
          - For Windows <=10 v1803: [Windows ADK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install)

            - **Select:** *Windows PE* & *Deployment Tools*
       2. **AIK:**

          - ImageX: [Windows 7 AIK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753)

            - **Run:** `StartCD.exe` > *Windows AIK Setup*
  2. **Create:**

     - [Microsoft WinPE Wiki](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive)

       - [Customize WinPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-mount-and-customize)
       - [Customize WinRE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/dn898523.aspx)
     - [Reboot.Pro Wiki](http://reboot.pro/topic/19156-create-a-bootable-winpe-50-x64-usb-drive/)
  3. **Boot it**

---

### Example: `/Get-WIMinfo` || `/Info`

```powershell
PS $  ls -file

  Directory: Z:\WIM

    Mode                LastWriteTime            Length  Name
    ----                -------------            ------  ----
    -a----        2018.12.24 03:34:13   95,019,530,773B  Base.wim
    -a----        2016.06.14 22:32:36              568B  DISM.cmd
    -a----        2016.05.17 05:36:10               97B  wimscript.ini

PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

    Index : 1
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Base (Drivers Only)
      Size : 22,710,283,446 bytes

    Index : 2
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Installed (No Customizations)
      Size : 45,591,850,754 bytes

    Index : 3
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Installed (Customized)
      Size : 94,958,267,312 bytes

    Index : 4
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Group 1 Installed (Customized)
      Size : 101,588,267,910 bytes

    Index : 5
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Group 2 Installed (Customized)
      Size : 101,905,314,237 bytes

    Index : 6
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1809: Updated Applications
      Size : 114,959,954,040 bytes

  The operation completed successfully.
```

```powershell
PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:1

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 1
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Base (Drivers Only)
      Size : 22,710,283,446 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 1
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 24288
      Files : 112665
      Created : 2018.05.05 - 13:56:47
      Modified : 2018.05.05 - 13:56:47
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:2

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 2
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Installed (No Customizations)
      Size : 45,591,850,754 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 1
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 45803
      Files : 203058
      Created : 2018.05.06 - 01:55:47
      Modified : 2018.05.06 - 01:55:48
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:3

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 3
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Installed (Customized)
      Size : 94,958,267,312 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 81
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 62409
      Files : 350446
      Created : 2018.06.01 - 19:09:51
      Modified : 2018.06.19 - 21:26:18
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:4

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 4
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Group 1 Installed (Customized)
      Size : 101,588,267,910 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 81
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 61908
      Files : 346074
      Created : 2018.06.08 - 21:54:02
      Modified : 2018.06.19 - 21:26:18
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:5

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 5
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Group 2 Installed (Customized)
      Size : 101,905,314,237 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 81
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 76113
      Files : 423408
      Created : 2018.06.09 - 20:38:36
      Modified : 2018.06.19 - 21:26:18
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:6

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 6
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1809: Updated Applications
      Size : 114,959,954,040 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17763
      ServicePack Build : 195
      ServicePack Level : 0
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 87659
      Files : 452028
      Created : 2018.12.24 - 04:27:13
      Modified : 2018.12.24 - 04:27:15
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: Third party cloning tools are fine if the user knows how to use them. The problem is some people watching too much YouTube and thinking that's enough.

Comment: 3rd party cloning tools are inefficient and carry a myriad of cons when compared to the native imaging Windows has always natively supported via `DISM`, and `ImageX` before it.

Comment: I've used the same Macrium Reflect as the OP many times without issues but that is because I know what I'm doing ;)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Simply because people rely on 3rd-party tools to image Windows does not mean they're doing so efficiently or in the best way possible _(much of that reliance is on the basic refusal by many Windows users to open a terminal)_. For Windows specifically, there is no other imaging solution that works better than native WIM/ESD imaging for a myriad of reasons: WIM/ESDs are impossible to corrupt, natively supported by all versions of Windows, can be applied while booted to Windows or from WinPE/WinRE, better compression ratios, no reliance on disk/partition layout, etc.